# How can I cite a company's website using IEEE style?

Tags: citations, software, ieee

I would like to use some information about the [Math Script RT Module](http://www.ni.com/labview/mathscript/). This might not be standard, so I cannot find any example online. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Software available online should be cited as a website, following the description given in the various [IEEE style guides](http://www.ijssst.info/info/IEEE-Citation-StyleGuide.pdf).  The easiest way to do this is typically with a citation management system like BibTeX.

Comment: Note that if either the author or "date updated" for a website are unavailable, the style guides allow you to exclude it.

Comment: Instead, you would just include the name of the company and the date you accessed the article. [This style guide](http://libguides.murdoch.edu.au/c.php?g=246207&p=1639795) has some good examples.